# replace "/" with "\/" in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to replace every `/` in a URL into `\/` but when I used `.replace()` method I get this:

```
string="path/dir/file.csv"
string.replace("/","\/")
string

>> path\\/dir\\/file.csv
```

Im not sure where the additional backward slash is being added. Any help?

Comment: Why are you adding backslashes in front of forward slashes? Forward slashes don't need to be escaped, but backslashes do, which is what you're seeing in your string.

Comment: Im trying to create a regex patten for that toy link to I can capture it further down my code

Comment: This code works on my machine...

Comment: OK, but like I said, forward slashes don't need to be escaped, even in regexes, so you're not really improving things by doing it. At worst, you're making more problems for yourself by having the backslashes.

Answer (score 0):

You are not accepting the string returned by the `replace` method.

```py
string="path/dir/file.csv"
string = string.replace("/", '\/')
print(string)
# path\/dir\/file.csv
```

Test python here: https://ideone.com/7uj4jn